# How can I make a multi-colored segmented progress bar in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, progress-bar, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a UserControl that acts as a sort of segmented progress bar.  Input would be a collection of objects, each object would have a category, a duration property, and status property.  The UserControl should stretch the width and height of the parent control.  Each item in the collection should represent a segment of the progress bar; color of the segment is related to the status, the width of the segment is related to the duration, and the text overlaid on the segment would be related to the category or something.

Example custom progress bar:
[image: s]

The text might be the collection item's ID, the top segment color would be related to status, the bottom color would be related to the category, and the width related to the duration.

Some of the options I've considered:

- Make a stackpanel and somehow define each items width and wrap the whole thing in a viewbox to make it stretch the height and width.  How could I control the text size, how do I make the content fit the height, how do I bind a stackpanel to a collection?
- Make an attached property for a grid control that would dynamically create columns and map the collection items to the grids.  Seems like a lot of work and I'm hoping theres a simpler solution since my requirements are pretty specific.
- Maybe theres a way to override a uniform grid to make it non-uniform?
- Maybe I should just go all code-behind and draw rectangles by iterating through my collection?

Either way, I am crossing my fingers that somebody might know a simple solution to my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a full working proposition of solution to the custom progress bar.

Code is here : http://1drv.ms/1QmAVuZ

[image: a customized progress bar]

**1 . If all the steps are not the same width, I prefer to use Grid with columns and different widths**

The columns are built dynamically based upon following class :

```
public class StepItem
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public String  Label { get; set; }
    public Brush Brush { get; set; }
}
```

**2. I chose to implement a CustomControl and inherit of `ItemsControl`**

CustomControl because I don't want to take care of implementing of the parts of the template of the `Progressbar`.

`ItemsControl` because :

-I want to provide to `ItemsSource` property a collection of `StepItems`

-`ItemsControl` can have some `DataTemplate` as template for each item

-`ItemsControl` can have any `Panel` like `Grid` as template presenting the collection of items

**3. The component has template in Generic.xaml**

-layoutGrid wil have the "continuous rainbow"

-overlayGrid will be displayed partially over the steps depending on progression or totally over (if no progress)

-`ItemsPresenter` will present the collection of `DataTemplates` corresponding to each `StepItem`

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ProgressItemsControl}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <Grid x:Name="layoutGrid">
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="overlayGrid" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**4. Customisation of the ItemsPanel to use a Grid (instead of vertical layout)**

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
            <Grid x:Name="stepsGrid" IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**5. In code behind of components, setting of the column width**

```
int i = 0;
foreach (StepItem stepItem in ItemsSource)
{
    total += stepItem.Length;
    var columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(stepItem.Length, GridUnitType.Star) };
    stepsGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);
    Grid.SetColumn(stepsGrid.Children[i], stepItem.Index);
    i++;
}
```

**6. Code behind for declaring Dependency properties that can be monitored**

(excerpt)

```
public int Value
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(ProgressItemsControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

**7. Usage of the component**

```
<local:CustomProgressBar
    x:Name="customProgressBar1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="32,49,0,0"      
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="379"/>
```

**8. Feeding the component with data**

```
private List<StepItem> stepItems = new List<StepItem>{
            new StepItem{
                Index=0,
                Label="Step1",
                Length=20,
                Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0)),
            new StepItem{
                Index=4,
                Label="Step5",
                Length=25,
                Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255,0,128,0)),
           },
        };
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressItemsControl1.ItemsSource = stepItems;
}
```

Regards